# Inequality between two sums of numbers of divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Let $D_b(m)$ be the number of divisors of $m$ that are less than $b$. Neil Sloane has suggested that the number of binary quadratic forms $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2$ with integral coefficients, discriminant $n^2-4$, and satisfying $A > 0$, $C > 0$, and $B > A+C$ is equal to

$$ \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} D_b(b^2-nb+1) $$

For a given integer $b \geq 1$, let $d_b(m)$ be the number of ways to nontrivially factor $m$ into two factors that are both congruent to 1 modulo $b$.  It turns out that for each integer $n \geq 1$, the sum

$$ \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} (d_b(b^2+nb+1) - 2) $$

is equal to the number of binary quadratic forms of discriminant $n^2-4$ of the form $(st+1)x^2 + (rst+r+s+t)xy + (rs+1)y^2$ with integers $r$, $s$, $t > 0$.  Since these forms are a subset of the earlier set of forms, we have the inequality

$$ \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} D_b(b^2-nb+1)  > \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} (d_b(b^2+nb+1) - 2) $$

The visual similarity of both sides is striking.  Is there a different way, especially a more direct way, to prove this inequality?

(I note that the individual numbers $D_b (b^2-nb+1)$ are sometimes lower and sometimes greater than the individual numbers $d_b (b^2+nb+1) - 2$.)

Comment: reference for Sloane suggestion? Also, are these indefinite forms, $B^2 - 4AC = n^2 - 4?$

Comment: His suggestion is at https://oeis.org/A257007 under "formula".  Yes, these are indefinite forms -- the condition $A > 0$, $C > 0$, and $B > A+C$ is the recent alternative definition of "reduced" form given by Zagier in "Zetafunktionen und quadratische Körper", section 13. (But your comment just made me realize I had the inequalities messed up -- I've fixed it now.)

Comment: Alright. I have copied the pages from Zagier's book on this. I was surprised to learn that the lengths of cycles of reduced forms were different, Zagier's reduction compared with Gauss/Lagrange.

Comment: Indeed.  In Franz Lemmermeyer's book-in-progress on BQFs, he writes "Zagier’s theory has much cleaner proofs than the classical one; on the other hand, Gauss’s theory is the one used for doing calculations because the coefficients of Gauss-reduced forms have only about half as many digits as those of Zagier-reduced forms."

Comment: Let me tell you something that came up: it turns out that the definition of reduction of Gauss actually resembles that of Zagier. I proved it in a post here on MSE. Anyway, Gauss reduced is $AC < 0$ and $B > |A+C|.$ If Franz is writing something I should tell him that. He may know.

Comment: Yes, he knows.  An old version is at http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/bf.pdf, and the condition you state is 1.34 on p.37.

Comment: The comparison rather reminds me of the that between the standard Euclidean algorithm and the least absolute remainder Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229079/inequality-between-two-sums-over-numbers-of-divisors